# why some text in my site page, hidden behind navbar (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just try to learn about bootstrap, and i have my  code write  into type php file, like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
           <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"> </script>
           <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
     </head>
     <body>
        <style>
              padding-top: 70px;
        </style>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation </span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wisuda  </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Loggin<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Mahasiswa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Prodi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">bb</a></li>
                    </ul>    
                </li>
             </ul>
        </div>
   </div> 
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
            <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fixed Footer -->
<div  class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
            <p>© my</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i test the preview 
[image]

Why some of the text ('*Bootstrap starter template*')   hiiden behind my navbar header?any help?

Comment: `<style>
              padding-top: 70px;
        </style>` makes no sense instead try it on `.container{ padding-top: 70px;}`

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, 
Thanks, but i have solve my problem with add `<style> body {padding-top: 70px;} </style> `

Comment: yours welcome ,either way worked out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of the `CSS` position of your `navbar`.

You can add `navbar-static-top` to your `navbar` like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
```

or you could add some `margin-bottom` to your `navbar` `CSS` class.

**UPDATE**

in your case you could replace

```
<style>
    padding-top: 70px;
</style>
```

with

```
<style>
    .navbar{
        margin-bottom: 50px !important;
    }
</style>
```

or add the margin to a custom `CSS` class of yours.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, but that's not working, my text still hidden behind navbar

Comment: Thanks, but i have solve my problem with add `<style>
    body {padding-top: 70px;}
  </style>`

Comment: With `navbar-static-top` the padding should not be needed. Or try `margin-bottom: 50px !important;`

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove Stick-top it is acting as relative property.
Removing Stick top solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing navbar-fixed-bottom. This solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Just add some padding at the top of your body will solve your problem.

Try adding:

```
<style>  
body {
padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```